# animation nodes can`t work with object that has a modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes

animation nodes can`t work with object that has a modifiers?
create spline from object node and use spline that has a shrink wrap modifief and subdivision modifier and I get a target curve object output that cant recognized modifiers on based curve.

Comment: AN can use modifiers with *Mesh input* or *BMesh from Object* nodes. You can create new spline from mesh input with applied modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

As Serge commented totally right, animation nodes will take the modifiers into account if you use "Mesh Object Input" and if you check "use modifiers".

[image]